# Proposal: Timestamp at StackExchange sites answers/comments without time after 3 days

Tags: feature-request, timestamps

My idea is that it would be some improvement, if after 3 days the timestamp is removed from your question/answer.

Thus, **only the date can stay** and it is quite enough. Still, **sorting by oldest would be an option**. Just without showing the hours and the minutes.

Comment: It would be great if you could mention why you think this is a good idea. :) Discussions (though this is really a feature-request) **need** to explain why they should be supported. Lacking that, it seems like a whim and your request is likely to be disliked.

Comment: @Catija - if it is not understandable without explanation, then it is probably a better idea to leave it as it is.

Comment: @Vityata Is there a particular reason you don’t want to share your motivation? Given that not doing so will reduce your chances (significantly) of seeing this change you want made?

Comment: @DanBron - In general, if I share my motivation then it can influence the decision making. I am not interested in it. If the reason is not obvious, then it is better to stay as it is.

Comment: @Vityata The entire point of posting feature requests on MSE is to influence decision making! You’re saying “I have an idea that I think will be an improvement over the status quo”, and then describing the idea ... but not why you think it’ll be an improvement. So by default the site will stick with he status quo. And, as you can tell from the comments & answers here, it definitely isn’t obvious to us.

Comment: @Dan Bron- I consider it a bit different - if noone (or random 5 users)cannot see the improvement then it is better to live without it.

Comment: Without knowing what problem you're trying to solve - suggested solutions, no matter how obvious are mostly useless.

Answer (score 8):

Knowing the order of answers coming in is pretty valuable to me.

Even three weeks later, being able to see the date and time in comparison with the other posts is useful to me. I admit that I may be an unusual case but you've failed to show what *harm* it does, so even a small benefit to some makes it of value.

Think about this... I ask a question... and then I disappear for a week. I come back to the site and there are two answers posted on the same day... they're very similar and they both solve my problem. I want to accept one of them but I can't choose between them... so I decide that I'll pick the older of the two... but they were posted the same day.

Yes, I can hover over the date on each to figure out which is older... but many users don't realize that feature exists. So, as it is now, I can easily see which is older, even if only by a minute or two.

For that reason, I think this should not be changed.

Comment: And how bout sorting by oldest? So cool feature that OP is trying to ***drop***.

Comment: Again, many people don't realize that is an option.

Comment: @Catija - ib general, it is not a good idea to ask a question and dissappear. And 3 days are quite enough time.

Comment: @nicael - sorting by oldest w/o showing hour and minutes is a good idea!

Comment: @Vityata This network isn't **only** Stack Overflow. You can tell me that "it's a bad idea"... that doesn't mean that you're right.

Comment: @Catija - I do not say that I am right. Not at all. On the contrary - if noone sees any reason in what I am asking for then I am definitely not right.

Comment: @Vityata you've said that three times already... I think it's enough.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't make much sense. This way you're just broadening the information about the date for no real reason, it is absolutely not evident why would one hide this info. *It's not an improvement*.

You're trying to move the cheese significantly. No one is going to benefit, as it will eventually cause chaos, *disorder, disorganization*, ***confusion, anarchy, entropy***.

I can predict with 100% accuracy that it's a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: Can you really not come up with even 1 reason?

Comment: @Vityata That's not **our** job... it's yours.

Comment: @Catija - if I am the only one that sees the reason for a change like this then it is really better not to implement it.

Comment: @vity thatz a pity, what a reas0n have u in ur mind?

Comment: I'm *dead **serious*** now!

Comment: @nucael - I am just discussing - if 5 people find it meaningless, then it is better to live without it.